# Writing \n to .txt file does not make a newline, just says \n

Tags: python, text, python-requests

So I have this code:

```
#! python3
import requests
import bs4
import time
import sys

messages = []

for i in range(3):
    # initiating request
    res = requests.get('https://supermariomakerbookmark.nintendo.net/')
    try:
        res.raise_for_status()
    except Exception as e:
        # handling error
        print('Error while requesting from bookmark:')
        print(e)
        time.sleep(3)
        sys.exit()

    # If gotten to this point, request has been succesfully made

    # creating soup element
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features='html.parser')

    # selecting elements
    elems = soup.select('div[class="course-title"]')
    if elems[0].getText() not in messages:
        print(elems[0].getText())
        messages.append(elems[0].getText())
    time.sleep(0.3)

with open('db.txt', 'w+') as f:
    data = '\n'.join(messages).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    f.write(str(data))
```

And you might have figured out, I'm trying to write out 3 random Mario maker levels on a file called `db.txt` (Obviously, I won't use it for only 3 levels, probably 500/700, but this is just an example).
The problem is, when I check the txt file it would be something like this:

```
b"foo\nbar\nbaz"
```

But I want it like this:

```
b"""
foo

bar

baz
"""
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with encoding.

Comment: Bytes are never shown with linebreaks but with escape sequences. Or in other words: your result is correct.

Comment: Ok, Well how do I make it with linebreaks?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
data = '\n'.join(messages).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

with

```
data = '\n'.join(messages)
```

Comment: yeah but if you did not know, some Mario maker courses have Japanese letters in them and stuff, so if that one gets picked, it will throw out an error

Comment: python support unicode let check output """
Dry Bowser's Note-orious Castle
<♪>2B&さん{皆さん}、夜更かしは、お肌に悪いわよ(^o^)
#001 Bulbasaur
"""

Comment: Does not matter anymore, just had to decode to utf-8 after encoding, thanks anyway..